# How to get the code element from fullname?

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, vs-extensibility

Consider the following:

```
Public class Foo()
{
   public BarClass Bar = new BarClass();
}
```

Here we have a simple class called Foo. Bar is a property of Foo of type BarClass. So when iterating through the code elements of Foo. Bar is simply a **property** and has no children.

However we do have access to the fullname of Bar.

How can I create a new CodeElement instance using the FullName property, so I can have access to the properties and methods (via the children collection) of Bar?

```
foreach (CodeElement child in Foo)
            {
// Bar shows up as a property, and you can access the Fullname here...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not 100% clear (Bar is not a property of Foo, it is a field, and has no children). But to navigate the code elements using the automation model (EnvDTE) you need to cast EnvDTE.CodeElement to a specific type (such as EnvDTE.CodeClass, or EnvDTE.CodeType) and use the Members property, not the Children property. See: [HOWTO: Navigate the code elements of a file from a Visual Studio .NET macro or add-in](http://www.mztools.com/articles/2006/MZ2006008.aspx)